# Is it safe to defrost cooked meat and eat it (without reheating)

Tags: food-safety, freezing

Say for example I had some marinated cooked chicken that I put in the freezer. Would it be safe to defrost this cooked chicken and put it in a sandwich without reheating it through first?

I know it's safe to eat cake out of the freezer, but I was wondering whether meat was different.

Comment: My question to you is: Why?  Why would you want to do such a thing?

Answer (score 6):

[There is no mention on the fact sheet](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/Factsheets/Chicken_from_Farm_To_Table/index.asp#4) of needing to recook previously cooked, frozen chicken. However, be mindful of proper defrosting techniques, as not doing so may open the food up to contamination.

Comment: http://www.fsis.usda.gov/Factsheets/Big_Thaw/index.asp says that you can refreeze w/o cooking if you thaw in the fridge, you should be fine eating it too.

Answer (score 2):

Iceland sell frozen pre-cooked chicken drumsticks that you just defrost and eat and do NOT require cooking according to their instructions.  They wouldn't be allowed to do that if it wasn't safe.

Answer (score 0):

It's safer than eating cooked meat than has been stored in the refrigerator. More bacteria grows in the refrigerator than the freezer.

Answer (score 0):

You can eat it without any food safety concern with proper defrosting/thawing of course.

Comment: Hello StevenXavier and welcome! Your post does not add any information that has not already been posted in other answers. Please refrain from posting duplicate information unless you can add to or expand on it. As you are a fairly new user, you may benefit from our Tour and Help pages. Both can be found under the 'help' dropdown at the top of the page.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't. Freezing does not kill everything that lives on food and cooking food to a minimum internal temperature kills most microbes (but not all).

**You're better off keeping raw chicken and marinade separate then combining as and when you require it.**

Taken from [US Department of Agriculture’s Food Safety and Inspection Service fact sheet](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/Factsheets/Focus_On_Freezing/index.asp):

> Is Frozen Food Safe?
>
> ...Freezing keeps food safe by slowing the movement of molecules, causing microbes to enter a dormant stage...
>
> ...Once thawed, however, these microbes can again become active, multiplying under the right conditions to levels that can lead to foodborne illness.

Taken from [FoodSafety.gov Safe Minimum Cooking Temperatures](http://www.foodsafety.gov/keep/charts/mintemp.html):

> Use this chart and a food thermometer to ensure that meat, poultry, seafood, and other cooked foods reach a safe minimum internal temperature.
>
> Poultry: 165F / 74C

Comment: I never thought I'd find myself saying this here, but this is actually going *too far* in terms of food safety. Cooked food will be safer having been frozen and properly defrosted than just sitting in the fridge - and refrigerated cooked meat is also considered safe. The USDA warning simply states that frozen food is not sterilized and that leaving it in the temperature danger zone for > 2 hours (cumulative from when cooking stopped to when the temperature went above 4° C) is just as unsafe for previously-frozen foods as it is for refrigerated.

Answer (score -3):

research shows that it is safe to eat cold chicken if it is cooked and stored in the freezer and then defrosted

Comment: What research in particular?